# MySQL INSERT INTO from PHP://INPUT multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have data (exact) from this HTTP POST:

> rowno=1.00000000&date_line=2014-10-07&name=Dan%20Volunteer&affiliation=Enterprise&checkno=1701&amount=20025.00000000&total=20250.00000000&notes=&date_deposit=&rowno=2.00000000&date_line=2014-10-07&name=Harper%20Lee&affiliation=Enterprise%20B&checkno=1702&amount=225

then this code to process

```
<?php

file_get_contents("php://input");

$db = null;
if (isset($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']) &&
strpos($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'],'Google App Engine') !== false) {
  // Connect from App Engine.
  try{
     $db = new pdo('mysql:unix_socket=/cloudsql/wonder:bread;dbname=loaf', 'root', '');
  }catch(PDOException $ex){
      die(json_encode(
          array('outcome' => false, 'message' => 'Unable to connect.')
          )
      );
  }
};

try {
  if (array_key_exists('name', $_POST)) {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO entries (name, affiliation) VALUES (:name, :affiliation)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':name' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']), ':affiliation' => htmlspecialchars($_POST['affiliation'])));
    $affected_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
    // Log $affected_rows.
  }
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
  // Log error.
}
$db = null;
?>
<?php

header("Content-type: application/vnd.fdf");
// read and store the data however you want
// reply with some FDF data
echo <<<RESPONSE
%FDF-1.2
1 0 obj
<< /FDF <<
/Status (Wham bam! File sent.)
>>
>>
endobj
trailer
<< /Root 1 0 R >>
%%EOF
RESPONSE;
?>
```

This http post has two records (row/recount count always varies), but only data from the last row is being inserted. Need all rows.

Comment: Row 1 is `rowno=1.00000000` up to `rowno=2.00000000` and that is row 2, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to stab at this one....I think what is happening is that you are just processing the return post as is, so the first `rowno` is being skipped over (rather the second `rowno` is overwriting the first). If you receive that post back as a string, you need to split it by `preg_match()` or `explode()` so that you can loop over it with your `try`.

Try this class on your string. This class will split the string into arrays based on rows. Then you need to take the resulting array `$insert` then process each array in your an `sql` loop...does that make sense?

```
class ProcessPost
        {
            public  static  function Split($value = '',$splitVal = 'rowno=')
                {
                    if(!empty($value)) {
                            // Explode by row values
                            $rows   =   explode($splitVal,$value);
                            $rows   =   array_filter($rows);

                            if(is_array($rows) && !empty($rows)) {
                                    foreach($rows as  $_row => $querystring) {
                                            parse_str($splitVal.$querystring,$_array[]);
                                        }

                                    foreach($_array as $row_key => $row_val) {
                                            if(empty($row_val))
                                                unset($_array[$row_key]);
                                        }

                                    return $_array;
                                }
                        }
                }
        }

    $test   =   'rowno=1.00000000&date_line=2014-10-07&name=Dan%20Volunteer&affiliation=Enterprise&checkno=1701&amount=20025.00000000&total=20250.00000000&notes=&date_deposit=&rowno=2.00000000&date_line=2014-10-07&name=Harper%20Lee&affiliation=Enterprise%20B&checkno=1702&amount=225';

    $insert =   ProcessPost::Split($test);
```

Comment: Thanks, Rasclatt. How would I implement your suggestion?

Comment: I made a couple edits. This is a better set-up. If you are stuck here let me know.

Comment: Thanks again! More like buried. I got as far as replacing $test = file_get_contents("php://input"); I imagine next is something like $array = array($insert) and foreach( $array as $key=>$value ) ???

Comment: The `$insert` will return an array and then, yes, you loop through that array and apply the sql inserts.

Comment: I will write it out for you to try. I'll also notate it to show you what I'm proposing.

Comment: No worries. It works perfectly. Thank you. But I'm more interested in your ProcessPost logic. Chiefly, for the array to be properly formatted from a http post, "rowno=" needs to be present first in the string pattern?

Comment: That's correct. I presumed it would be by default, or is that not usually there?

Comment: Yeah you could use any trigger in the query string and it will work. If you want to, you can add a trigger variable to the method so you can switch on the fly

Comment: Ok I added a `$splitVal` so you can split a string with any string portion. I am not sure if it's valuable to you you but the modification will work by default with `rowno=`.

Comment: Thanks. How does your change compare to previous code?

Comment: If you look at the inputs for the method, you can customize where it splits. Now instead of splitting `rowno=` you could split it somewhere else if you wanted to....I don't know if it's helpful or of use that way, but it still works by default with `rowno=`